# Get count for contact count per rep for each day PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am new to PSQL and wondering how to accomplish a total count of leads per rep for each day.
When I use the following query I get results that look like this from my table:

```
select * from leads
order by date desc
```

Output

```
index id            date              tag     rep       org_tag    org
910 901922  "2020-10-16 11:19:43"   "10848" "Carlos"    "10848"  "Sales"
878 900830  "2020-10-16 11:08:54"   "10778" "Nicholas"  "10778"  "Sales"
884 901040  "2020-10-16 11:08:37"   "10970" "Cheryle"   "10970"  "Sales"
767 888000  "2020-10-16 10:09:59"   "10970" "Cheryle"   "10970"  "Sales"
237 739370  "2020-10-15 16:42:18"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"   "Servicing"
641 880482  "2020-10-15 16:38:23"   "10848" "Carlos"    "10848"  "Sales"
657 881338  "2020-10-15 16:25:59"   "9922"  "Susan"     "9922"   "Sales"
```

What is the best way to only have 1 line for each rep for each day with a new column that displays the total number of leads for that date?

So with the data listed above I would want it to look like this:

```
                  date                rep              org        count
            "2020-10-16 11:19:43"   "Carlos"         "Sales"        2
            "2020-10-16 11:08:54"   "Nicholas"       "Sales"        1
            "2020-10-16 11:08:37"   "Cheryle"        "Sales"        2
            "2020-10-15 16:42:18"   "Michelle"       "Servicing"    1
            "2020-10-15 16:25:59"   "Susan"          "Sales"        1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need GROUP BY. If you google 'how to use group by in sql', you find lots of tutorials, such as [this](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-group-by/).

Comment: @jeroenh thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `group by` will do the things for you. As I understood you want count of row and latest date `rep` wise. Try this:

```
select 
max(date) "date"
rep,
org,
count(*) "count"
from leads
group by rep,org
order by  date desc
```